Does the Quran order The Jews and Christian to judge by the law of the Gospel and Torah they have According to Quran (5"68)
Say, ˹O Prophet,˺ “O People of the Book! You have nothing to stand on unless you observe the Torah, the Gospel, and what has been revealed to you from your Lord.” And your Lord’s revelation to you ˹O Prophet˺ will only cause many of them to increase in wickedness and disbelief. So do not grieve for the people who disbelieve.(5'68)
I dont undertsand why does it say to judge by the gospel and torah an the quran when they kinda controdict each other??
